# Unable to update Xcode server from Xcode 9.4.1 to Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10, osx-server, xcode-server

I updated my Mac Mini to Mojave also updated to Xcode 10, I've Xcode server configured in my Xcode 9.4.1 it was running even having some issues like couldn't able to install IPA directly into the device. Today I updated my Xcode and tried to update the Xcode server, it is throwing an error while starting Apache. Here is the screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem with a new macOS 10.14 installation.

Any chance you have the latest version of macOS Server (5.7.1)  installed too? Apparently the Xcode Server initialization process assumes that if you have macOS Server installed, then it can find a bundled version of Apache.

Since Apple [gutted macOS Server](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208312) recently, that assumption no longer holds, and the helper tools crash during initialization (check for `xcsreciperunner` crash logs).

I was finally able to turn on Xcode Server only after deleting the macOS Server app. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after removing macOS server app.

Comment: Nice. FWIW, I filed rdar://45261705 for this.

Comment: Update: it’s been duped to rdar://42141689

Comment: Update 2: the original bug has been closed.